# PhpSpreadsheet could not save to server

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to use PhpSpreadsheet to write and save excel file to File Server.
Here is my code:

```
$path = 'http://192.168.3.81/erpFile/'.time().'.xlsx';
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Excel2007');
$writer->save($path);
```

But I get the following error message:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: No such file or directory

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Exception
Message: Could not close zip file http://192.168.3.81/erpFile/1530169174.xlsx.
```

The directory permission already set to 777. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: `var_dump(is_dir(FCPATH.'erpFile'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use system file path. Like this:

```
$path = FCPATH.'erpFile'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.time().'.xlsx';
```

Comment: In any case you can't save a file by using a url. The above is correct. Are you 100% sure the folder actually exists?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. The folder was previously set to permission 755.

Comment: Using system file path solves my problem. Thank you.